# How to add dot in between numbers using java

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate customer entered input with java. i.e. we should allow numbers seven digits, after that if customer willing to enter numbers we should add '.' (dot) as separator.After separator we should allow only two digits, if any more digits enter we should throw an error.

Ex: 12345      --> Valid

Thanks,

Comment: Ex1: 1234567.56     --> Valid
Ex2: 1234567.678     --> we should throw an error to customer

Comment: You should try first doing it yourself and then come up here with what you did and what didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `str.matches("[0-9]{7}\.[0-9]{2}");`

Comment: This can be executed at runtime.Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "\\d{1,7}(\\.\\d{1,2})?";

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1234567").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("12345678").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1234567.").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1234567.1").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1234567.12").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1234567.123").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher("1.12").matches());
    System.out.println(ptrn.matcher(".12").matches());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply..I'm new to java..Here my need is , Taking Input from the User at a time we should add '.' and should allow two digits only..can you please give a complete code using scanner..Please help me out on this.

Comment: This can be executed at runtime